# Is there a name for a block-diagonal matrix with blocks of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a name for a real square matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_1 \\ -a_1 & 0 \\
& & 0 & a_2 \\ & & -a_2 & 0 \\
& & & & \ddots \\
& & & & & 0 & a_k \\
& & & & & -a_k & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
optionally with one or more additional rows/columns of 0?

For example, analogous to the fact that a real symmetric matrix is orthogonally equivalent to a real diagonal matrix, we can show that a real skew-symmetric matrix is orthogonally equivalent to a matrix of the form above.

Comment: These are tridiagonal real skew-symmetric matrices, and there is [an algorithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/167191/3111) which involves reducing general (real) skew-symmetric matrices to related forms.

Comment: @hardmath: Wouldn't just saying "tridiagonal" allow for, say, a nonzero entry in row 3, column 2? (And its negative in row 2, column 3.)  I want to exclude that.

Comment: Good point.  The phrase real Jordan form (see my link) comes to mind, for getting the two-by-two block diagonalization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The above is a **quasi-diagonal skew-symmetric** matrix. Obviously, I don't need to explain the skew-symmetric part.

The term "quasi-diagonal" means "block-diagonal with the diagonal blocks of order at most $2$". They are studied, for example, [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0965542506080021). The name is chosen with respect to quasi-triangular matrices which are often used in real Schur and similar decompositions (see [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9cwrJHFzo4cC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=quasi%20block%20triangular%20matrix&source=bl&ots=FfCku_RWtu&sig=K-25my83DNf2iVjtrTAxXGRCalk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=37GDUoOwIdTxhQeVyID4Cg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quasi%20block%20triangular%20matrix&f=false)).

The term itself is mentioned [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cyX32q8ZP5cC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22quasi-diagonal%20skew-symmetric%22%20matrix&source=bl&ots=JkDDQWk9QR&sig=7Td8BUaW4tfttPRndA9omYeABfM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_bKDUsu9D8bxhQfrtoG4CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22quasi-diagonal%20skew-symmetric%22%20matrix&f=false).